# Python 3 tkinter x scroll using arrow very slow

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview, scrollbar

In Python 3.x using a horizontal scrollbar and ttk treeview the x scroll by clicking on the arrows is very very slow, several pixels per second, I don't know how to fix this, here is a minimal example I made:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

app = tk.Tk()
t = ttk.Treeview(app)
t.pack(side="top",fill="both",expand=1)
xscroll = tk.Scrollbar(app,command=t.xview,orient="horizontal")
t.configure(xscrollcommand=xscroll.set)
xscroll.pack(side="top",fill="x")

tcols = ["header " + str(i)
         for i in range(50)]
t.config(columns=tcols)
for h in tcols:
    t.heading(h,text=h)

for i in range(5):
    t.insert("","end",
             text = "item" + str(i),
             values = ["value" + str(x) for x in range(49)])
app.geometry("{}x{}".format(800, 600))
```

it's the arrow clicking scrolling that is slow, the dragging using the bar is fine

Comment: change `xscroll.pack(side="top",fill="y")` to `xscroll.pack(side="top",fill="x")`

Comment: @SierraMountainTech done, thank you for that

Comment: I know that doesn't solve your slow scrolling with the arrows but should fix the format of the scroll bar.

Comment: I am reading some documentation on it [here](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/scrollbar.html) and it is saying `"The two triangular arrowheads at each end are used for moving the position by small steps. The one on the left or top is called arrow1, and the one on the right or bottom is called arrow2"`. I am still seeing if that increment can be increased but I am not sure it can.

Comment: It looks like the [documentation here](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/scrollbar-callback.html) describes how the buttons event works but I am not 100% sure how to modify it if it is even possible.

Comment: So I have made some progress. add this line below `xscroll.pack()`:  `xscroll.bind("<Button-1>", lambda e, tr=t: tr.tk.call(tr._w,'xview', 'scroll', 100, 'units'))`. This will result in the scrolling moving 100 units to the right no matter where in the scrollbar you are clicking. Now all that is left is to figure out how to bind it to the `arrow1` and `arrow2` parts of the scrollbar if possible.

Comment: @SierraMountainTech interesting, thank you. I was originally thinking of overriding the arrow press function in a custom tk.Scrollbar class, I tried printing dir(self) in the class but couldn't find the appropriate method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Trivia:

All you need to know that `xview` method of `XView` "mix-in"-class is just another one callback, that acts differently depending on a user interactions:

- If the user *drags the scrollbar slider*, `xview` is called as
  `xview(self, *('moveto', some_offset))`
- If the user *clicks in the trough*, `xview` is called as `xview(self, *('scroll', some_step, 'pages'))`.
- If the user *clicks the arrows*, `xview` is called as `xview(self, *('scroll', some_step, 'units'))`.

As you can see - not so complicated! Your problem lies in fact, that `some_step` is *always either 1 or -1 string value* in the last case, so all you need *just multiply* that value by some *multiplier*. Easy as pie!

### Solution:

As a solution, the most lightweight approach that I see here creates a derived class, that inherits from `ttk.Treeview` with overrided `xview` method.

Try this `Treeview` in your programm:

```
class CustomTreeview(ttk.Treeview):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        ttk.Treeview.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.vanilla_xview = tk.XView.xview

    def xview(self, *args):
        #   here's our multiplier
        multiplier = 100

        if 'units' in args:
            #   units in args - user clicked the arrows
            #   time to build a new args with desired increment
            mock_args = args[:1] + (str(multiplier * int(args[1])),) + args[2:]
            return self.vanilla_xview(self, *mock_args)
        else:
            #   just do default things
            return self.vanilla_xview(self, *args)
```

Comment: I wonder why they set the step to (I'm assuming it's in pixels?) one pixel, perhaps for fine adjustments? or perhaps it was coded when monitors were tiny

Comment: there's a slight problem with this approach, I'm not sure how to fix it, but if you call t.xview() from outside the class in a print function or something, to get the current scrolled position it returns a None type object as opposed to the tuple it normally returns, my programs has some functions which record the scrolled position in this manor. Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: @new_to_coding, Ah, you're right! There're missing return statements. "vanilla" function returns position if there're no arguments. Answer updated. Also, [units != pixels](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/scrollbar.htm#M24), maybe in your case it's better to swith to *pages* only.

Comment: I see, well, using units is working well for this widget's x scroll now it's been boosted, there doesn't appear to be any options in a scrollbars config to switch to pages in an easy way, thank you for your answer

Comment: @new_to_coding, No, there's an option! If you wonder how it feels, just change `mock_args` from answer to `mock_args = args[:2] + ('pages',)`. The good thing about this option - it acts relative to the geometry of window/treeview, when approach with `units` always acts in same fashion.

Answer (score 1):

One way we can speed up the scrolling is to create a few functions to help us along and use some bindings.

first we need a variable we can update to monitor if the mouse button is clicked down or released.

```
scrolling = False
```

next we need to create a few functions that we can use to start and stop the scrolling as well as creating a looping function that increases the speed of scrolling.

```
# uses that status of `scrolling` to keep scrolling or to stop for either arrow button
def scrolling_active(arrow, *args):
    global scrolling
    if scrolling == True:
        if arrow == "arrow1":
            t.tk.call(t._w,'xview', 'scroll', -10, 'units')
        if arrow == "arrow2":
            t.tk.call(t._w,'xview', 'scroll', 10, 'units')
        app.after(10, lambda a = arrow: scrolling_active(a))

# sets scrolling to True and activates the looping function to start scrolling
def start_scrolling(event):
    global scrolling
    scrolling = True
    scrolling_active(xscroll.identify(event.x, event.y))

# on mouse release this sets scrolling to false. This stops the loop above
def stop_scrolling(event): 
    global scrolling
    scrolling = False
```

Now we need to bind the start and stop functions to our scroll widget for mouse click and release.

```
xscroll.bind("<Button-1>", start_scrolling)
xscroll.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>', stop_scrolling)
```

With those changes we get arrows that scroll faster when clicked!

You can change the speed up to your liking by editing the int value in:

```
t.tk.call(t._w,'xview', 'scroll', -10, 'units')
t.tk.call(t._w,'xview', 'scroll', 10, 'units')
```

Take a look at the below code:

```
import Tkinter as tk
import ttk

app = tk.Tk()
t = ttk.Treeview(app)
t.pack(side="top",fill="both",expand=1)

scrolling = False
xscroll = tk.Scrollbar(app,command=t.xview,orient="horizontal")
t.configure(xscrollcommand=xscroll.set)
xscroll.pack(side="top",fill="x")

def scrolling_active(arrow, *args):
    global scrolling
    if scrolling == True:
        if arrow == "arrow1":
            t.tk.call(t._w,'xview', 'scroll', -10, 'units')
        if arrow == "arrow2":
            t.tk.call(t._w,'xview', 'scroll', 10, 'units')
        app.after(10, lambda a = arrow: scrolling_active(a))

def start_scrolling(event):
    global scrolling
    scrolling = True
    scrolling_active(xscroll.identify(event.x, event.y))

def stop_scrolling(event):
    global scrolling
    scrolling = False

xscroll.bind("<Button-1>", start_scrolling)
xscroll.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>', stop_scrolling)

tcols = ["header " + str(i)
         for i in range(50)]
t.config(columns=tcols)
for h in tcols:
    t.heading(h,text=h)

for i in range(5):
    t.insert("","end",
             text = "item" + str(i),
             values = ["value" + str(x) for x in range(49)])
app.geometry("{}x{}".format(800, 600))

app.mainloop()
```

Comment: thanks for your answer I learned a lot from the event stuff and "arrow1" and although it didn't really work (it kept scrolling when the button was released) I was able to create a tk.Scrollbar class where right clicking on an arrow would scroll the widget to the relevant end, if you want me to share the code in a separate solution page on stack let me know

Comment: @new_to_coding: The behavior you are seeing with the button not working properly is a bug I have noticed in some versions of python 3.6.1 and 3.6.2. It works as intended on 2.7

Comment: Ah okay, I suspected it was a Python 3 difference, thanks

Comment: @new_to_coding Its not actually a python 3.X difference but rather a version of 3 that is having the problem. It does work on 3.5 and other versions of 3. So far I have only confirmed the bug on 3.6.1 and 3.6.2.